Mass balance in a vacuum system
I’m working on simulating a system where a rough vacuum is used to evaporate water. To do this, I need to perform a mass and species balance on the vacuum side of the system, but I’ve been having some trouble.
The system consists of a water reservoir and a chamber where the vacuum is applied, separated by a membrane.
Ideally, only water vapor can pass through the membrane and enter the chamber. The mass flux (water vapor) entering the vacuum chamber is given by the following equation:
$$j_w=K(p_{sat}-p_{w,vac}),$$
where $K$, $p_{sat}$ and $p_{w,vac}$ are the membrane mass transfer coefficient ($kg\,m^{-2}\,s^{-1}\,Pa^{-1}$), saturation pressure of water in the water reservoir and the partial pressure of water vapor in the vacuum chamber. So far, things are fine, because both $K$ and $p_{sat}$ are known, and the amount of mass entering the system per unit time is
$$\dot{M}_{in}=j_w\times A,$$
where $A$ is the membrane surface. A vacuum pump is used to keep the absolute pressure low. I know what the absolute pressure $p_{vac}$ in the vacuum side is, and from this, I can infer two things:

Since $p_{vac}>p_{sat}$, there is some air inside the vacuum chamber.

I also know what the suction flow rate $Q_{suc}\,(m^3\,s^{-1})$ is: I can calculate it from the characteristic curve of the pump ($p_{vac}\, \text{vs}\,Q_{suc}$).


As the system reaches steady state, there can be no mass accumulation in the vacuum chamber, so
$$\dot{M}_{in}-\dot{M}_{out}=0$$
My problem arises when calculating $\dot{M}_{out}$. One possible approach I’ve considered is
$$\dot{M}_{out}=\rho_{vac}Q_{suc},$$
but I have no way of calculating $\rho_{vac}$ without knowing the composition (mass fraction $\omega$ of air and water) inside the vacuum chamber.
Do you have any idea on how can I derive an equation for $\dot{M}_{out}$?
P.S.: the vacuum pump used is a Steam Ejector

If "only water vapor can pass through the membrane and enter the chamber", the steady state composition in the chamber should be only water. If this is not the case, you need a more nuanced initial assumption about the composition entering the chamber.

Your arguments makes a lot of sense. However, if the lowest $p_{vac}$ the pump can achieve is larger than the saturation pressure of water in the chamber, if all the gas inside the chamber is vapor it should condense and the total pressure would fall below $p_{vac}$, no?

What is the difference between $p_{w,vac}$ and $p_{vac}$? Are there different temperatures? If not, then if $p_{vac}>p_{sat}$, the flow is from the vacuum chamber into the water reservoir according to your first equation.

In this simplified model I assume that the vacuum chamber is isothermal. The measurements I have give $p_{vac}>p_{sat}$ and a positive vapor flux entering the vacuum (so that $p_{sat}>p_{w,vac}$). I fear the possibility of a leak that allows air to enter the vacuum chamber.
